# Magento Get Selected Filter In Layered Navigation

Tags: php, magento

In Magento, if "color" attribute is chosen in layered navigation, values of the "color" are automatically disappears and results are getting displayed.How to retrieve the name of the selected filter?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All the applied filters are stored in layer state object. You can easily retrieve them by using the following snippet:

```
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
```

It will return you an array of filter item objects. You can retrieve name and applied value of a single filter item by doing something like this:

```
foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
    $item->getName(); // Name of the filter
    $item->getLabel(); // Currently selected value
    $item->getFilter()->getRequestVar(); // Filter code (usually attribute code, except category filter, where it equals "cat")
}
```

Comment: $item->getFilter()->getRequestVar(); // Attribute Code of the filter

Comment: How do I get id of attribute "color"?

Comment: Great answer! Anyone know how to get a code(or number id) of the filter? So for example in my case colour filter id is 187, I looked it up in the database, but how to I get that with php?

Comment: Can someone please update this to show the Magento 2 version of this. Thx!

Comment: @ivan chepurnyi how we can write the above snippet in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can get filter's attribute code or id through this code:

```
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
    echo $item->getFilter()->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeId();
    echo $item->getFilter()->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode();
}
```

Comment: How to apply your code into custom module.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2:
$this->getLayer()->getState()->getData("filters")